# How to import .dat file in Google Co-lab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am implementing famous Iris classification problem in python for 1st time. I have a data file namely iris.data. I have to import this file in my python project. I try my hand in Google Colab.

Sample data

Attributes are:

1.sepal length in cm
2. sepal width in cm
3. petal length in cm
4. petal width in cm
5. class:

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

I worte

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
FILE_PATH = "E:\iris dataset"
MAIN_FILE_NAME = "iris.dat"

data = np.loadtxt(FILE_PATH+MAIN_FILE_NAME, delimiter=",")
```

But it did not work and through errors.

But it worked when I wrote the code in Linux. But currently I am using windows 10 and it did not work.

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When constructing the file name for `np.loadtxt`, there is a `\` missing, as `FILE_PATH+MAIN_FILE_NAME = 'E:\iris_datasetiris.dat`. To avoid having to add `\`manually between `FILE_PATH` and `MAIN_FILE_NAME`, you could use `os.path.join`, which does this for you.

```
import os
import numpy as np

FILE_PATH = 'E:\iris dataset'
MAIN_FILE_NAME = 'iris.dat'

data = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(FILE_PATH, MAIN_FILE_NAME), delimiter=',')  # not actually working due to last column of file
```

On the other hand, I am not sure why it did work with Linux, because numpy is not able to convert the string "Iris-setosa" into a number, which np.loadtxt tries to do. If you are only interested in the numeric values, you could use the `usecols` keyword of `np.loadtxt`

```
data = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(FILE_PATH, MAIN_FILE_NAME), delimiter=',', usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: OSError: E:\iris dataset/iris.dat not found.  I got this error.

Comment: The error message sounds to me that you tried to run the above code from under Linux, without changing the paths. You would have to adapt the `FILE_PATH` to point to your folder in the Linux file system where the file `iris.dat` is located.
Under windows, the above shown code snippet works for me, so I am not sure where the error might come from when you run it from Windows 10.